# Implementing an interface on a list

Tags: java, arrays, interface

I have an array of 10 items in Java (item is a class). Only 4 out of the 10 implement the `Breakable` interface.

I'd like to iterate over the array, and if the item is Breakable - do `item[i].break()`;

```
public static Item[] createItems()
{
    return new Item[]{
            new PaintBoard("PaintyBoardy", 1000, 545,600),
            new Lamp("Lampy", 2000,300),
            new Glass("Sharpy", 200, 1000),
            new Ball("Roundy", 150, "Black"),
            new PaintBoard("secondPainty", 1001, 545,600),
            new Lamp("Lumpy", 2000,300),
            new Glass("Sharper", 200, 1000),
            new Ball("Circular", 150, "Black"),
            new PaintBoard("Boardy", 1000, 545,600),
            new Lamp("Limpy", 2000,300)
    };
```

This is the method I use to create my array. Only Lamp and Glass implements the `Breakable` interface.

I've tried sending the `item[i]` to a method

```
public static void breakItem (Breakable item)
{
    item.Break();
}
```

I've tried casting `(Breakable)item[i].break();`, nothing seems to work.

Comment: "nothing seems to work." ? what doesn't work? compilation? execution? what is the error?

Comment: Please include compiler error messages and runtime error messages.

Comment: FYI: [*JEP 433: Pattern Matching for switch (Fourth Preview)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/433)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `instanceof` check and a cast:

```
for (final Item item : createItems()) {
  if (item instanceof Breakable) {
    ((Breakable) item).break();
  }
}
```

In newer version of Java, the type check and the cast can be combined:

```
for (final Item item : createItems()) {
  if (item instanceof Breakable breakable) {
    breakable.break();
  }
}
```

Comment: the first method doesn't work, but the second one does. Thanks!

Do you have any idea why wouldn't it work for the first one?

Comment: @NatiShen-Gordon why not? "does not work" is the worst error description you can give somebody. What does not work? Is it a compiler error, a runtime error, an unexpected result, no result, …?

Comment: (Breakable) item.break() will compile error.
((Breakable).item).break() will work. 

Do you have any idea why that would be?

Comment: Becasue the precedence of `.` is higher than of the casting operator. Not using parentheses is equal to writing `((Breakable) item.break())` is is casting the value returned by the method. Compare: `((Breakable) item.break())` vs `((Breakable) item).break()`. That's just how the Java language is defined.